# Why is my program printing "null" instead of the string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that will print the temperature's for each day of the week. I don't know why my code is printing "null" instead of each day of the week. I've never seen this error before (I'm in a beginning programming course) and I can't find any info in the textbook. This is my code so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TempsInOneWeek {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
    final int NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 7;
    String[] dayOfWeek = new String[NUMBER_OF_DAYS];
    int[] temp = new int [7]; //array of 7 temperatures for 7 days of the week
    int tempForDay = 0;
    int i = 0; //loop variable

    System.out.println("Enter the temperature for each day, beginning with Sunday.");

    for (i = 0; i <= temp.length; ++i) {
        temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek[i] + "/'s temperature was: " + temp[i] + " degrees.");
    }

    dayOfWeek[i] = "Sunday";    
    dayOfWeek[i] = "Monday";
    dayOfWeek[i] = "Tuesday";
    dayOfWeek[i] = "Wednesday";
    dayOfWeek[i] = "Thursday";
    dayOfWeek[i] = "Friday";
    dayOfWeek[i] = "Saturday";

    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
}
```

Obviously the arrays are in the wrong place but it doesn't affect the output right now so I wanted to show that I'm at least trying here. Really my only question is how to get the day of the week to print. And maybe a little direction on what to do with my two arrays above.

Comment: What happens when you run it in the debugger?

Comment: Ok, remove all of the assignments after the loop. Let's just fix the `dayOfWeek` array declaration. That needs to be once before the loop. `String[] dayOfWeek = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };` - and in your loop use `<` (not `<=`).

Comment: And the reason you currently get `null` is because `String[] dayOfWeek = new String[NUMBER_OF_DAYS];` creates an array that can store 7 `String`(s) but does not set those seven to any value. Thus you have seven `null`(s). As for using `dayOfWeek[i]` to set the day of the week values... you would need to **specify** the value of `i` and do it *before* the loop. `dayOfWeek[0] = "Sunday";` - or use the syntax from my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move these following assignments before for loop

```
dayOfWeek[i] = "Sunday";    
dayOfWeek[i] = "Monday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Tuesday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Wednesday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Thursday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Friday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Saturday";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to retrieve the data from your array...

```
System.out.println(dayOfWeek[i] + "/'s temperature was: " + temp[i] + " degrees.");
```

...you haven't actually put anything into the array at this point.

When you create your array...

```
String[] dayOfWeek = new String[NUMBER_OF_DAYS];
```

This creates the array and populates each index with **null**

Remember, when you declare and initialise an array, unless you explicitly populate the array, it will be filled with default values for the array's type (String in your case - and the default value for String is null).

So, you need to move the lines of code that actually populate the array to *before* the point at which you attempt to retrieve the data...

```
dayOfWeek[i] = "Sunday";    
dayOfWeek[i] = "Monday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Tuesday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Wednesday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Thursday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Friday";
dayOfWeek[i] = "Saturday";

for (i = 0; i <= temp.length; ++i) {
    temp[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    System.out.println(dayOfWeek[i] + "/'s temperature was: " + temp[i] + " 
    degrees.");
}
```